# Ember js - how to trigger a controller action when route is activated

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to trigger a controller action each time a controller is transitioned to (the 'modeller' route), but I can't seem to get it working. My router.js file is:

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  actions: {
    loading: function() {
        this.controllerFor('modeller').send('loading');
    },
    didTransition: function() {
        this.controllerFor('modeller').send('didTransition');
    }
  }
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('modeller', { path: 'modeller'});
  this.route('welcome', { path: '/'});
});
export default Router;
```

And my modeller controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: 'modeller',

  loading: function () {
    console.log("loading")
  },

  didTransition: function () {
    console.log("didTransition")
  },
});
```

But I can't get any of those actions to log to the console. Any pointers greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

Probably should have mentioned I'm using Ember 2.1.0!

So the solution I used was setupController - but I also needed to put that into a specific modeller route file under app/routes/modeller.js. Previously I was trying to do everything in the app/router.js and it didn't work there. So the final solution is:

```
# app/routes/modeller.js
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this.controllerFor('modeller').activate();
  }
});
```

and ..

```
 # app/controllers/modeller.js
 export default Ember.Controller.extend({
   needs: 'modeller',

   activate: function () {
     console.log("activate")
   },
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`didTransition` is a method on `Route` rather than on `Controller` which is why that method isn't getting called.

If you need to effect the controller from the route, the hook you would want would be [setupController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController).

Best practice is to use [components](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/components/defining-a-component/) which would enable you to use the component [lifecycle hooks](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/components/the-component-lifecycle/).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use willTransition in Route.

When a transition is attempted, whether via {{link-to}}, transitionTo, or a URL change, a willTransition action is fired on the currently active routes. This gives each active route, starting with the leaf-most route, the opportunity to decide whether or not the transition should occur.

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/routing/preventing-and-retrying-transitions/

**model hooks**

activate & deactivate hooks of Ember.Route will also be called for every transition between routes, either of these two also you can use and inside 
you can call controller action method.

```
deactivate: function() {
    this._super();
     this.get('controller').send('actionName');
}
```